# numpy array matrix-like multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following definition:

```
class Transform:
    mat_ = np.ones([2, 2], dtype=float)

    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.mat_ = mat

    # vec should be a column vector
    def r_mult(self, vec):
        return self.mat_ @ vec.T
```

I'm using it to initiate an object, like

```
t = transform.Transform(np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1]], dtype=float))
```

Then, I call

```
t.r_mult(np.array([1, 0.0]))
```

however, the answer I get from the PyCharm console is:

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [2., 0.]])
```

Which is a point-wise multiplication and not a matrix-vector type I would expect. Direct calculation without the class in the middle works as expected

```
np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1]], dtype=float) @ np.array([1, 0.0])
```

leads to

```
array([1., 2.])
```

Is there something I should know about python classes, or why the multiplication does not work?

Comment: I added a return to your `r_mult` function and checked the result. I get the second result. Can you verify you did exactly as you say?

Comment: @jared, yep, i had return previously, but the result was the same

Comment: Are you sure that you're using this exact code? I directly copied the code and get the expected result. Are you sure you didn't change the `@` for `*`? What Python and numpy versions are you using?

Comment: Look at `np.array([1,2]).T`.  Any change?  Do you want `[[1],[2]]`?  You might also want to review what `matmul` does when one argument is 1d.

Comment: I've resorted to rerun the console, and things finally looks ok. Thank you all.